# Одно ли это и тоже?

Tags: javascript, условия

Вот это

```
if (typeof(item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'undefined' ||  item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'NaN'))
```

Тоже самое что?

```
if (typeof(item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'undefined') || typeof (item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'NaN'))
```

Comment: результат будет одинаково неверным в обоих случаях из-за неверного использования `typeof`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, а как правильно?

Comment: Смотря что именно ты хочешь проверить

Comment: @Grundy что item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == undefined или NaN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

И да и нет.

Во-первых, оба ваши примера ошибочны, так как `typeof` во всех вариантах будет выдавать `boolean`, ведь вы проверяете не тип поля объекта, а тип логической операции:

```js
const item = { PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE: undefined }

console.log(typeof(item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'undefined' ||  item.PROPERTY_BAL_VALUE == 'NaN'))
```

Во-вторых, `NaN` имеет тип `number`, а не `NaN`, поэтому форму записи `typeof(some) == NaN` использовать бессмысленно.

В-третьих, нет смысла использовать `typeof` в таких случаях, ведь можно просто проверить используя сравнение с `undefined` и функцию `isNaN`:

```js
const item = {
  PROPERTY_UNDEFINED: undefined,
  PROPERTY_NAN: NaN,
}

console.log(item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED === undefined || isNaN(item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED))
console.log(item.PROPERTY_NAN === undefined || isNaN(item.PROPERTY_NAN))
```

Кстати, кроме того, стоит учитывать, что `undefined` - это falsy-значение, поэтому, в некоторых случаях стоит использовать строгое сравнение (`===`) или действительно `typeof`:

```js
const item = {
  PROPERTY_UNDEFINED: undefined,
  PROPERTY_NULL: null
}

console.log("item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED == undefined:", item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED == undefined)
console.log("item.PROPERTY_NULL == undefined:", item.PROPERTY_NULL == undefined)
console.log("item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED === undefined:", item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED === undefined)
console.log("item.PROPERTY_NULL === undefined:", item.PROPERTY_NULL === undefined)
console.log('typeof(item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED) == "undefined":', typeof(item.PROPERTY_UNDEFINED) == "undefined")
console.log('typeof(item.PROPERTY_NULL) == "undefined":', typeof(item.PROPERTY_NULL) == "undefined")
```

Comment: то есть undefined и NaN это не типы? ну я нубас

Comment: @Dmitriy `undefined` - это и значение и, тип, а вот `NaN` - только значение.

Comment: все теперь я просвещённый =)